# Specific solution of the Burgers equation $u_t + u u_x =0$ with boundary condition $u(x,0)=e^{-x^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have difficulty with finding a specific solution to the below PDE

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
u_{t}+uu_{x}=0\\ 
u(x,0)=e^{-x^2}
\end{matrix}\right.$$

My attempt:

It is stright forward to get the general solution using method of characteristic 
$$\frac{dt}{1} = \frac{dx}{u}=0$$
$$\frac{dt}{dx} =u$$
$$c=x-ut$$
thus
$$u(x,y)=f(c)=f(x-ut)$$

How then the specific solution using the given boundary condition $u(x,0)=e^{-x^2}$   can be derived?

Could I simply substitute for $x$ and $t=0$? How then the resulting equation could be simplified further?
$$u(x,0)=f(x)=e^{-x^2}$$
$$u(x,y)=e^{-(x-ut)^2}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$u$ is constant along the characteristics. So given $x,t$, you need to find $x_0$ such that 
$$ x_0 = x - u(x_0,0) t \tag{1}$$ 
And then you have that $f(x,t) = u(x_0,0) = e^{-x_0^2}$.

Unfortunately, solving the equation (1) often cannot be done explicitly. This is for two reasons:

1. As in your case, the function $u(x_0,0) = e^{-x_0^2}$ is too complicated to invert.
2. Also as in your case, there will be points for which there are multiple possible $x_0$ (for one fixed pair $(x,t)$).

---

One way to go about it is to write your solution in "hodographic coordinates". This means that instead of writing it as $(x,t)$, we write it in $(x_0, t)$. Vis:

$$ u(x_0 + e^{-x_0^2}t, t) = e^{-x_0^2} $$